# What are the instructions by our scriptures on how to win a chaste wife with integrity?

Tags: dharma

I am looking to get married in the next few years and would like to know where in our scriptures it is written how to win a chaste wife.

I want to stress not the victory of winning a chaste wife, but how to develop the characteristics of that man who deserves to have a chaste wife.

I want to build my character to an ideal man according to our scriptures. I read a little in Maha-Nirvana-Tantra in Swami Vivekananda's vol.1 about the duties of a householder, but it doesn't give instructions for the transition from Brahmacari to householder.

I read one verse from Kamasutra, but was utterly dissapointed at it since it says that one has to use sly tricks to win a woman. As soon as I read that I felt like burning that book.

thank you